# Determining "reachable" objects linked via many-to-many relations

Tags: python, django, django-models

My model is setup with many-to-many relationships to separate items into groups and categories:

```
class DownloadableResourceGroup(models.Model):
    pass

class DownloadableResourceCategory(models.Model):
    pass

class DownloadableResource(models.Model):    
    res_categories = models.ManyToManyField(DownloadableResourceCategory, blank=True)
    res_groups     = models.ManyToManyField(DownloadableResourceGroup, blank=True
```

Each view has a resource group assigned to it, which provides initial filtering of the resources. Then, I would like to apply further filters based on categories. My question is - how do I get list of `DownloadableResourceCategories` from `DownloadableResources` filtered by a `DownloadableResourceGroup` without iterating over them? I only want to show categories present on the `DownloadableResources` that are in the current view and do not want to show categories that do not have any items in them.

To further illustrate what I am doing:

```
# fetch relevant DownloadableResources
items = active_collection.downloadableresource_set.all().order_by("title")

# get only categories present in the items above
relevant_categories = THIS_IS_WHAT_I_AM_AFTER
```

Comment: What is `items` here?

Comment: @AKS DownloadableResource

Comment: Could you also add your view where you have tried what you want to do?

Comment: @AKS added example above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the relevant categories as following:

```
relevant_categories = DownloadableResourceCategory.objects.filter(
                           downloadableresource__in=items).distinct()
```

Do note the use of `distinct()` since it is a m2m relationship you can get category multiple times. `distinct` will only return the unique categories in this case.